# How do I find the width & height of a terminal window?

Tags: terminal

As a simple example, I want to write a CLI script which can print `=` across the entire width of the terminal window.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
echo str_repeat('=', ???);
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print '=' * ???
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
x=0
while [ $x -lt ??? ]; do echo -n '='; let x=$x+1 done; echo
```

Comment: I created this tiny node.js lib for consistently getting the correct window-size https://www.npmjs.com/package/window-size

Comment: This article covers the 3 main answers below, all in one place: https://howto.lintel.in/find-width-height-terminal-linux/.

Answer (score 764, accepted):

- `tput cols` tells you the number of columns.
- `tput lines` tells you the number of rows.

Comment: `echo -e "lines\ncols"|tput -S` to get both the lines and cols see: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tput.htm

Comment: `tput` is a great command with [lots of commands](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20983251/24874) for reading the state of the terminal, controlling the cursor and text properties, and so on.

Comment: Handy alias, for example: `alias dim="echo $(tput cols)x$(tput lines)"`, which might result in `80x50`.

Comment: This Q&A *probably* belongs on either the unix or superuser SE sites.

Comment: One problem with tput: there is no --quiet option to silence the "unknown terminal" or "No value for $TERM" error messages and 2>/dev/null breaks it too. stty size seem to do better.

Comment: @bishop the alias command you provided gets evaluated when the shell gets sourced. You need to use single quotes for the alias command. Like so:

`alias dim='echo Terminal Dimensions: $(tput cols) columns x $(tput lines) rows'`

Comment: `tput` as defined by POSIX doesn't support `cols` or `lines`. This is a non-standardized extension. This solution is not reliable.

Comment: requires ncurses, and requires calling two commands, while you can `stty size` it away

Answer (score 141):

In bash, the `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` environmental variables should be able to do the trick. The will be set automatically upon any change in the terminal size. (i.e. the [SIGWINCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGWINCH) signal)

Comment: However, these environment variables are only available to bash, and not to any programs that run inside bash (like perl, python, ruby).

Comment: That does not work in anything but the interactive bash session (if you run the script it is not interactive any longer). The only place you can use it in a script is the prompt_command in bash.

Comment: Actually, it does work in non-interactive scripts, if you set the `checkwinsize` option. For example, this non-interactive script will print the dimensions of the terminal on which it is run : `shopt -s checkwinsize; (:); echo $LINES $COLUMNS` (the `checkwinsize` option only initializes the variables after waiting for a subshell to finish, which is why we need the `(:)` statement)

Comment: `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` are updated after `SIGWINCH` is sent, actually after any interactive command execution. If you try to update `PS1` with `trap SIGWINCH` you can't use `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS`, they keep old values ((

Comment: `LINES` and `COLUMNS` are only set as *shell variables* by bash. Bash will not set them as *environment variables*, unless you export these shell variables.

Comment: @Br.Bill `COLUMNS` and `LINES` are defined by POSIX, they have nothing to do with bash and nowhere is defined, that its the task of the shell to set them. POSIX says that the user can set them to desired values: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08

Answer (score 114):

And there's `stty`, see [stty: Print or change terminal characteristics](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stty-invocation.html), more specifically [Special settings](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Special.html)

```sh
$ stty size
60 120 # <= sample output

# To read into variables, in bash
$ read -r rows cols < <(stty size)
$ echo "rows: $rows, cols: $cols"
rows: 60, cols: 120
```

It will print the number of rows and columns, or height and width, respectively.

Or you can use either `cut` or `awk` to extract the part you want.

That's `stty size | cut -d" " -f1` for the height/lines and `stty size | cut -d" " -f2` for the width/columns

Comment: This style cannot work with PIPE, suggest use tput style.

Comment: the problem with tput is that it is not always available while stty is available in every tty. thanks for that info!

Comment: `stty` is not from coreutils. stty is POSIX standard and thus pretty much available everywhere, also on BSD systems that definitely won't have coreutil Coreutils just implements the majority of the POSIX terminal standard.

Answer (score 23):

```
yes = | head -n$(($(tput lines) * $COLUMNS)) | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but a great demo script.

Comment: What a great example!

Comment: how the heck did I miss the `tr` command all these years? (facepalm)

Comment: What language is this? It looks vaguely like a shell script with syntax errors. (In shell you can't have spaces around the assignment equals sign, and the first pipe seems out of place.)

Comment: `yes '='` will output an infinite amount of '=' lines and the following commands organize enough to fill the terminal

Comment: Nice example; if you want a bashism even more cryptic: `eval printf '=%.0s' {1..$[$COLUMNS*$LINES]}`.

Answer (score 12):

To do this in Windows CLI environment, the best way I can find is to use the mode command and parse the output.

```
function getTerminalSizeOnWindows() {
  $output = array();
  $size = array('width'=>0,'height'=>0);
  exec('mode',$output);
  foreach($output as $line) {
    $matches = array();
    $w = preg_match('/^\s*columns\:?\s*(\d+)\s*$/i',$line,$matches);
    if($w) {
      $size['width'] = intval($matches[1]);
    } else {
      $h = preg_match('/^\s*lines\:?\s*(\d+)\s*$/i',$line,$matches);
      if($h) {
        $size['height'] = intval($matches[1]);
      }
    }
    if($size['width'] AND $size['height']) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return $size;
}
```

I hope it's useful!

**NOTE**: The height returned is the number of lines in the buffer, it is not the number of lines that are visible within the window. Any better options out there?

Comment: Note a problem with this: the output of this command is locale-specific. In other words, this will not work as-is on another Windows locale. This is what I get on Windows 7: http://i.imgur.com/Wrr7sWY.png

Comment: Added an answer with a solution to that. +1 though!

Answer (score 11):

On POSIX, ultimately you want to be invoking the `TIOCGWINSZ` (Get WINdow SiZe) `ioctl()` call. Most languages ought to have some sort of wrapper for that. E.g in Perl you can use [Term::Size](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::Size):

```
use Term::Size qw( chars );

my ( $columns, $rows ) = chars \*STDOUT;
```

Comment: Thanks for this – led me in the right direction. Elixir: `:io.columns` Erlang: `io:columns().` http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#columns-0

Comment: There's no `TIOCGWINSZ` in the POSIX standard and `ioctl()` is only defined for the obsolescent STREAMS feature.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in lyceus answer, his code will fail on non-English locale Windows because then the output of `mode` may not contain the substrings "columns" or "lines":

[image: mode command output]

You can find the correct substring without looking for text:

```
 preg_match('/---+(\n[^|]+?){2}(?<cols>\d+)/', `mode`, $matches);
 $cols = $matches['cols'];
```

Note that I'm not even bothering with lines because it's unreliable (and I actually don't care about them).

**Edit:** According to comments about Windows 8 (oh you...), I think this may be more reliable:

```
 preg_match('/CON.*:(\n[^|]+?){3}(?<cols>\d+)/', `mode`, $matches);
 $cols = $matches['cols'];
```

Do test it out though, because I didn't test it.

Comment: Your method doesn't work in Win8. I get more than one `---` line. http://i.imgur.com/4x02dqT.png

Comment: @Mark Well, great, that is just BEAUTIFUL. Thank you Windows. <3 (on a more relevant note: I'll see into how to fix that... when Windows 9 comes out :P).

Comment: This is the way I do it: `$mode = \`mode\`; list($rows, $cols) = array_slice(preg_split('/\n/', substr($mode, strpos($mode, 'CON:'))), 2, 2);`. And then I just replace everything but numbers.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov I wonder what happens if there's languages with order like `CON device status:`? Maybe matching something like `CON.*:` would work better.

Comment: @CamiloMartin, the thing is, that "CON:" string remains the same. I checked ru locale, I see the same structure. Lines are on the on the 2nd row after "CON:" string. Columns are on the 3rd.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov How do you know it remains the same on all languages? I can imagine the phrasing where `CON` can be the last word may not be usable in *some* languages. What I think is certain is that the word `CON` is in a line that ends with `:`. But even that may not be true :P I just wish they had kept all of command line in English.

Comment: Well, I'm not providing a universal solution after all, just point out an idea how I do it.

Comment: That looks like it works, yeah. Can you explain why you're searching for anything except a `|` though?

Comment: @Mark I was actually questioning myself that exact thing. Why the heck did I do that? In doubt, I just assumed there was some reason and went with it, lol.

Comment: `mode` is slow. Using `mode con /status` is faster, as it excludes all the modems and just gets the console status. Still not lighting fast, but much better than single `mode`. Also, if you use `mode con /status`, your first RE works as well, as it only returns the console status.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by @pixelbeat's answer, here's a horizontal bar brought to existence by `tput`, slight misuse of `printf` padding/filling and `tr`

```
printf "%0$(tput cols)d" 0|tr '0' '='
```

Answer (score 3):

## Getting the window width

This shell code makes a global variable `$TERM_SIZE` track the size of the terminal window:

```sh
set_term_size() {
    TERM_SIZE="$(stty size 2>/dev/null)" && [ "$TERM_SIZE" ] ||
        TERM_SIZE='25 80'
}
trap set_term_size WINCH
set_term_size
```

It tries `stty size` before falling back to assuming that the terminal is 25 lines high and 80 characters wide. POSIX does *not* mandate the `size` operand for [`stty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html)`, so the fallback is needed.

You can then access the columsn argument by using the shell's limited string substitution capabilities:

```sh
echo "${TERM_SIZE% *}" # Prints the terminal's height.
echo "${TERM_SIZE#* }" # Prints the terminal's width.
```

Of course, the scripting language you use likely offers a library that takes care of that for you -- and you should use it.

## Printing a line

Once you know the width of the terminal, printing a horizontal line is easy, for example, by abusing `printf`'s string padding:

```sh
printf '%*s\n' "${TERM_SIZE#* }" '' | 
tr ' ' -
```

The first line tells `printf` to print as many spaces as there are columns (by abusing string paddin) to a pipe. Note, POSIX does *not* mention the `*` syntax, so this may not be as portable as the code above.

The second line tells `tr` to read from that pipe and replace every space with a hypen.

Answer (score 1):

There are some cases where your rows/LINES and columns do not match the actual size of the "terminal" being used. Perhaps you may not have a "tput" or "stty" available.

Here is a bash function you can use to visually check the size. This will work up to 140 columns x 80 rows. You can adjust the maximums as needed.

```
function term_size
{
    local i=0 digits='' tens_fmt='' tens_args=()
    for i in {80..8}
    do
        echo $i $(( i - 2 ))
    done
    echo "If columns below wrap, LINES is first number in highest line above,"
    echo "If truncated, LINES is second number."
    for i in {1..14}
    do
        digits="${digits}1234567890"
        tens_fmt="${tens_fmt}%10d"
        tens_args=("${tens_args[@]}" $i)
    done
    printf "$tens_fmt\n" "${tens_args[@]}"
    echo "$digits"
}
```

Comment: This is good, if your `stty` won't give you **real size!** Very good @pourhaus !
I just changed the number in line `for i in {1..14}` for checking the number of columns from 14 to 25.