# Allign left and right in python?

Tags: python

I've seen a question on justifying a 'print' right, but could I have text left and right on the same line, for a --help? It'd look like this in the terminal:

```
|                                                     |
|Left                                            Right|
|                                                     |
```

Comment: Are you using ArgParse for your command-line parser?

Comment: For right-justifications, you first need to know how wide your total output space is. Do you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `sys.stdout` for this:

```
import sys

def stdout(message):
    sys.stdout.write(message)
    sys.stdout.write('\b' * len(message))   # \b: non-deleting backspace

def demo():
    stdout('Right'.rjust(50))
    stdout('Left')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print()

demo()
```

You can replace `50` with the exact console width, which you can get from https://stackoverflow.com/a/943921/711085

Comment: couldn't you use `print message,` (note trailing comma)?

Comment: nifty. I've commented it, and edited it so it works in the interactive python prompt, and in both python2 and python3. Replace `50` with the value you'd get from http://stackoverflow.com/a/943921/711085 for exact accuracy.

Comment: @andrewcooke: The `\b` "rewinds: the cursor to the beginning of the line, so I'm actually overwriting the line when I print out `Left`. You could use `print`, though. @FJ did.

Comment: right, but there's no need to mess around with sys.stdout, you can still use idiomatic python print (there's nothing special about \b that requires sys.stdout).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pretty simple method:

```
>>> left, right = 'Left', 'Right'
>>> print '|{}{}{}|'.format(left, ' '*(50-len(left+right)), right)
|Left                                         Right|
```

As a function:

```
def lr_justify(left, right, width):
    return '{}{}{}'.format(left, ' '*(width-len(left+right)), right)

>>> lr_justify('Left', '', 50)
'Left                                              '
>>> lr_justify('', 'Right', 50)
'                                             Right'
>>> lr_justify('Left', 'Right', 50)
'Left                                         Right'
>>> lr_justify('', '', 50)
'                                                  '
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I'd like to propose a more elegant solution that "fails gracefully" when the combined text's length exceeds the desired length.

```py
def align_left_right(left: str, right: str, total_len: int = 80) -> str:
    left_size = max(0, total_len - len(right) - 1)  # -1 to account for the space
    return format(left, f"<{left_size}") + " " + right


def main():
    print("1.", align_left_right("|left", "right|"))
    print("2.", align_left_right("|", "right|"))
    print("3.", align_left_right("|left", "|"))
    print("4.", align_left_right("|left", "right|", total_len=20))
    print("5.", align_left_right("|left", "a longer text that doesn't fit|", total_len=20))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output :

```
1. |left                                                                     right|
2. |                                                                         right|
3. |left                                                                          |
4. |left         right|
5. |left a longer text that doesn't fit|
```

You could make a more full-fledged version using [`textwrap.shorten`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.shorten) to keep the total size constant even when one or both strings are too long.