# What is termios.TIOCGWINSZ

Tags: python

I want to get the size of the terminal.  I am using this functionality:

```
import sys, struct, fcntl, termios

s = struct.pack('HHHH', 0, 0, 0, 0)
t = fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdout.fileno(), termios.TIOCGWINSZ, s)
print(struct.unpack('HHHH', t))
```

But what on earth is `termios.TIOCGWINSZ`?

Comment: Unfortunately the python `termios` module documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/termios.html#module-termios) doesn't give a list of the `ioctl` `request` constants that it brings in... but you can go look at the source code:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3a5b0d8988491d9408b22bceea6fd70b91345724/Modules/termios.c#L319 and for more information refer to your particular OS manual pages or, for more standard ones, the standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-linux-console-window-width-in-python . `os.get_terminal_size()`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a magic constant determined by the system you are running on resp. by the terminal driver.

In combination with `ioctl()`, it serves to tell exectly what you want, in your case call IOCtl to Get the Window Size. Thus the name `TIOCGWINSZ`, `IOC`tl to `G`et the `WIN`dow `S`i`Z`e.

[This bit of documentation](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_495.html) might help you clear things up.

Comment: @KevinBurke The way I wrote this was intended to clarify why the constant is named this way.

Comment: I admit it looks ugly, however.