# ws_xpixel and ws_ypixel

Tags: linux, terminal, ioctl

Here is the code I am using to print the resolution in pixels of the current terminal.

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct winsize ww;
    ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ww);
    printf ("x-pixels %d\n", ww.ws_xpixel);
    printf ("y-pixels %d\n", ww.ws_ypixel);
    return 0;
}
```

I used [this](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_495.html) as `winsize` reference.
But the code prints only zeros. If I use `ws_col` or `ws_row` it works fine.

Please help, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code of glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/bits/ioctl-types.h#L69) you will see that `ws_col` and `ws_row` **are not actually used**.

```
/* Type of ARG for TIOCGWINSZ and TIOCSWINSZ requests.  */
struct winsize
{
  unsigned short int ws_row;    /* Rows, in characters.  */
  unsigned short int ws_col;    /* Columns, in characters.  */

  /* These are not actually used.  */
  unsigned short int ws_xpixel; /* Horizontal pixels.  */
  unsigned short int ws_ypixel; /* Vertical pixels.  */
};
```

P.S.: Read also this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21210/74926), if you are not sure why I am pointing to glibc.

Comment: Thanks !, so how to get sizes in pixels?

Comment: Try to get the pixel width of one character.

Comment: Maybe using [XTerm Control Sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22785601/1807667) will be a solution for your case.

Comment: ws_col and ws_row are not actually used... by the kernel itself. But the kernel does store and pass this information from TIOCSWINSZ calls to TIOCGWINSZ calls. ws_xpixel and ws_ypixel generally work on terminals with SIXEL support.

Answer (score 0):

Those two values are set by *some* terminal emulators.

Please see the [VTE feature request to set these fields](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=782576) which summarizes my recent findings. (VTE is the actual terminal emulation widget behind `gnome-terminal` and many others.)