# How to avoid splitting the console output in Python?

Tags: python

**Example**

```
long_string = "I dont want this string to be splitted"
print(long_string)
```

If I print the string and the console is fullscreen, everything is fine. Output:

```
I dont want this string to be splitted
```

But when the console is small and the string doesn't fit, the following happens. Output:

```
I dont want this stri
ng to be splitted
```

This just looks really ugly. Is there a way to avoid it?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do to resolve it? Split it by word? If the word is too long, how are you going to resolve that?

Comment: By default you can set the size of the console, so it does'nt give that output

Comment: If possible, splitting the output by char would be an option. But setting a default size for the window isn't really what I want. For instants `airodump-ng` does a good job splitting the output by character.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782703/how-to-get-terminal-size-or-font-size-in-pixels

Comment: What do you mean by "splitting the output by char"? Do you mean keeping whole words together, if possible, where "words' are separated by spaces?