# Printing strings vertically aligned in Python

Tags: python, text-alignment

Assuming I have a number of strings, each requiring a line break when printed, how can I vertically align them without giving a fixed number of characters per line?
Example:
String:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

they are too long to be printed on one line each, so in the output a line break is introduced like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbb
```

but I would like to have:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
aaa
bbb
```

I store chars as a list.

Comment: Sort by length?

Comment: What data structure are you using to store these strings?

Comment: How would sorting by length help? Both strings are of similar length, it's just about how they are displayed...

Comment: You really want to break up the strings after the line break, continuing with partial strings??? In your example aaaaaaaa is half-way printed, then bbbbbbb, then the rest of aa and bb. Sorting by length would achieve that.

Comment: this is precisely what I would like to do!

Comment: Then split the strings to the display length and sort. Python's sort should be stable, so the result will be what you want.

Comment: when you say you store chars as a list.. do you mean you do this just prior to output? And is  this a must?

Comment: @dornhege I was looking for a command like find_display_length, but couldn't find any, what would you suggest?

Comment: Have your font a fixed width ?

Comment: Yep, you mean using sth like 
console.getTerminalSize() and then divide by the width?

Comment: OK, so your actual question is how to find the display width if you print to a terminal?

Comment: What will determine the length of these strings before a line break is introduced?

Comment: @lhcgeneva the only way to accomplish that is via terminal commands.  If you want fixed length strings sorted the way you specified, you need to have a fixed length in the code otherwise you have to use terminal commands to set the output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-console-window-width-in-python

Comment: If there is no cooler automated way (putting things in a table, letting the table do the line break or similar) then yes, this is my question