# Ask multiple user input in single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using **Python 3** and I'm looking for a way for the program to ask 2 user inputs in a single line.

Example of the output I'm looking for:

```
enter first input:                      enter second input:
```

However the only way I know for asking multiple user inputs is this:

```
first_input = input("enter first input: ")
second_input = input("enter second input: ")

#output
enter first input:
enter second input:
```

Is the one I'm looking for possible? If yes, can someone teach me how to do that?

Comment: ask user to enter two numbers separated by space and then press enter.Then Split() :)

Comment: This is possible, but it requires [a lot more effort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html); something not easy if you are beginning. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: hmm...i think i'll give it a shot...can you show me how with explanations in between the codes???

Answer (score 1):

```
choices = raw_input("Please enter two input and seperate with space")
value1, value2 = choices.split(" ")
```

Now if you enter `1 56` or something like this `value1` will be `1` and `value2` will be `56`.
You can choose another seperator for `split` function.

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what the asker wants.

Comment: This is alternative way which I know. Let him decide that.

Comment: well this just helped my friend, thanks for that...however, i'm looking for a different one

Answer (score 1):

This is largely environment-dependent.

The following is a windows-only solution:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes

def get_stderr_handle():
    # stdin handle is -10
    # stdout handle is -11
    # stderr handle is -12
    return windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-12)

def get_console_screen_buffer_info():
    csbi_ = CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO()
    windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(get_stderr_handle(), byref(csbi_))
    return csbi_

class CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO(Structure):
    """struct in wincon.h."""
    _fields_ = [
    ("dwSize", wintypes._COORD),
    ("dwCursorPosition", wintypes._COORD),
    ("wAttributes", wintypes.WORD),
    ("srWindow", wintypes.SMALL_RECT),
    ("dwMaximumWindowSize", wintypes._COORD),
]

csbi = get_console_screen_buffer_info()
first_input = input("enter first input: ")
cursor_pos = csbi.dwCursorPosition
cursor_pos.X = len("enter first input: ") + len(first_input) + 1
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(get_stderr_handle(), cursor_pos)
second_input = input("enter second input: ")
```

The following is a linux solution, which uses backspace characters. There are some implementations of `get_terminal_size()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6550596/1115577) if you're using an older python version.

```
from shutil import get_terminal_size
first_input = input("enter first input: ")
second_input = input("\b"*(get_terminal_size()[0] - len("enter first input: ") - len(first_input) - 1) + "enter second input: ")
```

Comment: didn't work for me...the output was a series of boxes that moves when i click between them

Comment: What terminal you using, and which os?

Comment: by terminal you mean pc? ..i'm using an asus laptop with windows 7 as os ...i've got a question about your answer, is the one i'm looking for really that much dependent on the environment of my terminal; or is this 1 of the few answers i'm going to encounter?

Comment: Try the windows only solution, tested on windows 7.

Comment: the output did not change for me; i think i lack something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59013/discussion-between-user3921890-and-simonzack).

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
import sys
inputarr=sys.stdin.read().split()
print("input 1:",inputarr[0])
print("input 2:",inputarr[1])
```

you can use any other delimiter

notify me me if this not what you are looking for !

Comment: Its easy sys includes System-specific parameters and functions and stdin is the file object for interpreter’s standard input stream . sys.stdin.read() will read from standard input till EOF is reached while sts.stdin will read one line at a time .

Comment: hmm..okay..but, i didn't get the inputarr[] part

Comment: Sorry i screwed up :P it has to be sys.stdin.read().split()  "sys.stdin.read()" reads the input file till EOF is reached and split() without any parameter is similar to split(" ") ie it will remove all the white-spaces and put the elements on a list