# Print dashes across full width of screen

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm looking to print a dash `"-"` until the end of the user's screen.

Basically my program would print a line of text and then a line of dashes beneath it and then another line of text. This would be done so that the user can easily distinguish between the first and second line.

Something like this:

```
First line of text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Second line of text
```

Is there a way for me to do this using the standard python 2.6 libraries. I cannot use any additional libraries such as `texttable` or a newer version of Python.

Comment: Are you looking at [how to get console window width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-console-window-width-in-python)?

Comment: For which operating system is this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I believe I can use how to get console window width to find out the width of the window. There is a lot of data being presented to the user and if I leave a blank line it is not readable.

Comment: @fredtantini: Yes I believe that this is what I was looking for Thank you! I'll review it and see if I can make it work for me.

Comment: @Thibaut: This is for a Linux operating systems.