# Determining terminal width in IPython qtconsole

Tags: python, ipython, qtconsole

When running IPyhton qtconsole, how can the number of columns be determined for maximizing text display so that it looks good in the current setting ?

Comment: related: [How to get console window width in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/566746/4279)

Comment: It can't. We know that's not ideal for some situations, but it's part of a general principle that code shouldn't know too much about what may currently be displaying its output.

Comment: it looks like the code is out there in the qtconsole (ConsoleWidget.sizeHint()), but I can't figure out how to get to that from the script running underneath the qtconsole

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the width and height in ipython_qtconsole_config.py

```
# c.IPythonWidget.width = 81
# c.IPythonWidget.height = 25
```

Answer (score 0):

sizeHint() didn't work well for me (didn't resize with the window), but size() worked fine.

```
In [10]: ipyida.ida_plugin.obj.widget.parent.size()
Out[10]: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1241, 894)
```

To get access to the running instance, I had to patch the .py file that imported qtconsole and insert this:

```
globals()['obj'] = self
```

In my case, the qtconsole is launched from IDA, so I can then access via:

```
instance be accessed via:   
    import ipyida           
    ipyida.ida_plugin.obj.*
```

To calculate the number of character columns, you will have do something like this:

```
f = ipyida.ida_plugin.obj.widget.parent.fontInfo()
f.pixelSize() # 11
w = ipyida.ida_plugin.obj.widget.parent.size().width() // f.pixelSize()
```