# how to get result from many list in same line in python

Tags: python

I have three list:

```
alist=[1,2,3,4,5]
blist=['a','b','c','d','e']
clist=['@','#','$','&','*']
```

I want my output in this format:

```
1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e
@ # $ & *
```

I am able to print in correct format but when i am having list with many elements it's actually printing like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 ..........................................................................
................................................................................

a b c d e ............................................................................
......................................................................................

@ # $ & * .............................................................................
.......................................................................................
```

but I want my output like this:

```
12345....................................................................
abcde...................................................................
@#$&*...................................................................

............................................................... {this line is from alist}
................................................................ {this line is from blist}
................................................................ {this line is from clist}
```

Comment: Are we talking about a fixed width here or about a variable width depending on how wide the terminal screen is?

Comment: What the dots are supposed to represent? What "this line is from alist" means? I don't see any line with dots in any of your lists, so it seems you expect your code to do something more than what you described in your question.

Comment: dots represent more elements... and its because of width of terminal

Comment: @mohammadshahbazKhan: So split a list by the width of terminal?

Comment: I dont know how to do that

Comment: and what if there are three long variable instead of list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
term_width = 80
all_lists = (alist, blist, clist)
length = max(map(len, all_lists))
for offset in xrange(0, length, term_width):
    print '\n'.join(''.join(map(str, l[offset:offset+term_width])) for l in all_lists)
```

This assumes terminal width is 80 characters, which is the default. You might want to detect it's actual width with curses library or something based on it.

Either way, to adapt to any output width you only need to change `term_width` value and the code will use it.

It also assumes all elements are 1-character long. If it's not the case, please clarify.

If you need to detect terminal width, you may find some solutions here: [How to get Linux console window width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-console-window-width-in-python)

Comment: what if we have three long variable instead of list

Comment: @mohammadshahbazKhan This code works with both strings and one-character lists equally. It won't work with lists composed of items with *different* size, as in this case you'll need to do some smart wrapping.

Comment: Use `import os; term_width = os.get_terminal_size().columns` to get the terminal width.

Comment: @KevinGuan, that only works in Python 3.x. I have added a reference to a relevant question which has a number of more generic solutions.

Comment: Oh, see that just now.

Comment: how can i give one line gap between them .. only when new line starts for alist,blist and clist