# Clear wrapped lines with curses

Tags: bash, terminal, stdout, curses, tput

When I run the following code in bash, in a terminal that's not too wide (currently my terminal is 97 columns wide), I don't see the expected behavior

```
# foo.sh
tput sc  # save cursor
for i in $(seq 10); do    
    printf "%s" "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    tput rc  # restore cursor
    tput ed  # clear to end of screen
done
echo "foo"
```

The lines don't actually get cleared: [image]

However, if I change the string to be shorter than the width of the terminal, so that it doesn't wrap, then it works fine and curses clears the line so that only the final "foo" shows up on the screen.

```
# bar.sh
tput sc  # save cursor
for i in $(seq 10); do    
    printf "%s" "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    tput rc  # restore cursor
    tput ed  # clear to end of screen
done
echo "foo"
```

So my question is: How do I clear the screen from the cursor down to the bottom in the presence of line wrapping, and... what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: Maybe duplicate(?) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169869/clearing-the-last-line-in-the-terminal-when-text-wraps-around

Comment: It worked ok in my terminal. A guess is that the terminal doesn't finish wrapping before `tput ed` is executed. Try putting `sleep 0.5; tput ed`. It could also just be a quirk of the terminal you're using, try the example in some other terminals. If it's important, I would wrap the text in the script, using eg `fmt -w` or `fold`, rather than rely on a terminal, which may not wrap text at all.