# shutil.get_terminal_size() does not change

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, curses, shutil

I am using curses to print a pretty nice console UI, and I need for that something to be dependent of the terminal size. For this, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-linux-console-window-width-in-python), that I could use `shutil.get_terminal_size`.
So I'm doing this code :

```
def display(self):
    size_x,size_y = shutil.get_terminal_size()
    print(size_x,size_y)
    window_stat = curses.newwin(size_y,size_x//2-5,0,0)
    window_alert = curses.newwin(size_y,size_x//2-5,0,size_x//2+5)
    window_alert.addstr("\n   " + self.alert2string())
    window_stat.addstr("\n   " + self.stat2string())
    window_alert.box()
    window_stat.box()
    self.stdscr.refresh()
    window_stat.refresh()
    window_alert.refresh()
```

But the fast is that, it is working perfectly the first time I call the function, but if I use my mouse to change the terminal size and recall the function, the result of `shutil.get_terminal_size()` will always stay the same. (120 30).

Do you have any idea of where it could come from ? 
(I'm running Windows actually, and I'd like it to work under all common OS)

Thanks a lot everyone !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, that's because the application using [**`shutils`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#querying-the-size-of-the-output-terminal) is (in this case) using the Windows console api to create a *buffer* which has a fixed-size.  In more conventional Unix-like applications (rather than `shutuils` attempt at high-level and portable), one would make a `SIGWINCH` handler that notifies the application of the size-change. With Windows, you'd have to get that from the event-loop — which is completely obscured by the `shutils` interface.

It happens to "work" with Unix because `shutils` doesn't have to actually pay attention to those notifications.  The operating system's terminal driver (usually) can return the updated information.

You might file a bug-report against `shutils`, to get its developers to take that into account in their design.