# Here's a way to get window size in python

Tags: python, linux

I have seen numerous questions similar to this but yet to see one directly related.  Hopefully I can add to the information that has been floating around over the years.

Lets say I have my little CLI app.py and I want to "fancy" it up, for example.

```
#########################################################################
                         Welcome to my App
#########################################################################


someInput>
```

Let's see how many ways there are to skin this cat.

Comment: maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-linux-console-window-width-in-python

Comment: You are expected to perform basic research and make an effort. Please show the relevant code and state where you are having problems. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not asking a question but clearing up one. I see many questions that are asked not knowing what they are truly asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of to accomplish this is in the following way.
Just think about it: we don't really care about the DPI or the resolution; we just want to adjust our output to our terminal window size. Precisely, the columns or width.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

size = int(os.popen('tput cols').read().strip())
print('#' * size)
print('Welcome to my App').center(size))
print('#' * size,'\n\n')
i = input('What's your name? ')
```

We are using `popen()` to run a shell command `'tput'` to get the columns(`'cols'`) of our window, getting the answer with `read(`), striping the trailing new line with `strip()`, converting it to an integer and then saving it to the variable `size`.

Next we are printing pound signs(#) based on the number of columns (`size`)

Next we are using `center()` to align out text to the middle of the window(`size`).

The rest I think is self explanatory we just added 2 new lines to the end of our bottom pound signs(#)

I hope this clears some things up for anyone that hasn't figured out how to ask the right question.

Links:
[popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=popen#os.popen), [read()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=read#os.read), [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip), [center()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=center#str.center), [tput](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput)

Answer (score 1):

I usually add some ASCII art as a 'splash screen' for console apps. For example, you may use [this site](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20) to generate your ASCII. Then store it into a text file and print from your code:

```py
def print_splash():
    with open('splash', 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```