# Python - Formatting So When Text is Printed It Appears From the Right Side Not Left Side

Tags: python

The code below shows letter by letter of the sentence in parenthesis but it types from the left side when I run the program. Is there any way I can make the text print from the right side?

```
from time import sleep

hello = ("Hello")


for character in hello:
    print (character, end = "", flush = True)
    sleep(0.1)

print(" ")
```

Comment: Do you mean print the string in reverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.rjust()` to right-justify a string to fit in a certain character length, padding the excess with a chosen character:

```
>>> "Hello".rjust(10, ' ')
#  '     Hello'
```

However, you can't  just right-justify everything you print in the terminal window, because *you don't know how large the terminal window is going to be*. You can maybe assume the width will be 80 characters at minimum, but that's not a hard gap.

You'll probably get more mileage messing with your terminal's display settings than you will writing a python program to automatically right-justify your text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format alignment options but you still have to set the string's total length though.

```
'{:>10}'.format('Hello')
```

- '>' means align right.
- '10' is the character length you deisre.

More format options [here](https://scientificallysound.org/2016/10/17/python-print3)

In case you really need the terminal size you can extract like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943921/9806031).