# Python print - how to clear output before print end="\r"

Tags: python, output

Normally `print ("{}".foo, end="\r")` works well.

But the exception is when `foo` is long, and next time `foo` becomes short. The output becomes incorrect. Below is an example:

```
import time
print ("{}".format(1111), end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print ("{}".format(2), end="\r")
```

First Output:

```
1111
```

Final Output (after 2 sec) - which is **wrong**:

```
2111
```

Expected Output

```
2
```

### Attempts

Tried using `flush=True` with `print`, and `sys.stdout.flush()` but without luck.

Tested in Jupyter Notebook and iPython.
Any idea how to optimize this in a simple way?

Comment: Well, I am getting the desired output: `1111` and then after 2 secs, `2`

Comment: I am getting only `2` after the 2 secs. The `1111` doesn't appear.

Comment: I believe the behaviour is platform-dependent (possibly even may differ between different terminals on the same platform). An universal method would be to right-pad the shorter output with spaces.

Comment: I test this on Windows. What I know from answers below is - the output is right for Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this if it works

```
import time
print ("{:<5}".format(1111), end="\r")
time.sleep(2)
print ("{:<5}".format(2), end="\r")
```

Comment: You could replace the 5 by `shutil.get_terminal_size().columns`, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-linux-console-window-width-in-python it should be cross-platform.

Comment: This is the best answer until now. Marked it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a class instance to remember what was printed last and overwrite it with spaces:

```
import time

class OverwriteLast:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last = 0
    def print(self,s):
        if self.last:
            print(' '*self.last, end='\r')
        self.last = len(s)
        print(s, end='\r')

over = OverwriteLast()

over.print("{}".format(1111))
time.sleep(2)
over.print ("{}".format(2))
```

Output as requested

Comment: Right way to go and it works. I will wait for 1 more day to see if there will be simpler answer. Many thanks for this solution.