# Python prevent Print() in new lines if terminal width is smaller than the length of words

Tags: python-3.x

My code is `print("Current progress : something", end = "\r")` and keep repeating

Normally if the terminal is enough wider than the length of words to print, it looks normal as below :
[image: Normal]

But if the length of words are longer than the width of terminal, it will start to making a new line and instead of carriage return to the line before, it will start at the new line
[image: Abnormal]

My idea is not to print the excess code if the width is too small

And also set the specific width and height to the terminal of the user, I had used `pywin32` to set this, but `pywin32` not available to Linux user, so which module can I use in Linux with the same function with `pywin32`

Edit :
I had made a code as below, but it still can't solve my problem

```
Length = shutil.get_terminal_size()[0]
print (" "*(Length-10), end = "\r") # Clear Last Line
ProgressPrint = f"Current Progress : {somephrase}\t{somephrase}\t{somephrase}"
print ( ProgressPrint[0:Length-10], end = "\r")
```

Comment: try this, *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-linux-console-window-width-in-python*

Answer (score 0):

(This only answers the first part of question)

Why not try the f-string format specifier?

```py
f"{some_name:10.10}"
# This truncate & limit some_name's length to 10

max_len = 10
f"{some_name:{max_len}.{max_len}}"  # same but with name instead of literal.
```

Demo:

```py
import shutil
import time

width = shutil.get_terminal_size()[0]
print(f"Detected console width: {width}")


def limit_output(stuff_to_print, prefix="", suffix=""):

    free_length = width - len(prefix) - len(suffix)
    print(f"{prefix}{stuff_to_print:{free_length}.{free_length}}{suffix}", end="\r")


for n in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    limit_output("Meow Moo Bark" * (10 - n), f"Iteration {n} / ", "/ Nice suffix")

print()
```

Output:

```
Detected console width: 128
Iteration 2 / Meow Moo Bark Meow Moo Bark Meow Moo Bark Meow Moo Bark Meow Moo Bark Meow Moo Bark Meow Moo Bark Meo/ Nice suffix
```

Comment: Can you please solve my 2nd question too :)
I can't find the solution for changing the terminal width and height in Linux

Comment: @Shinonon I'll try tinkering with it but might fail to find an answer. What you want is controlling size of the terminal? I never heard of stuff that can do that so far on linux.. Feel free to not accept my answer as I just wanted you to solve half the problem at least!