# How to fmt.Print("print this on the center")

Tags: go

Is possible, with `fmt.Println("...")` to print a string with center alignement of the shell?

Comment: So do you know the width of the shell or is that part of what you need to work out how to do?

Comment: This can tell you the width and height:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263890/how-do-i-find-the-width-height-of-a-terminal-window

Comment: @miltonb, your link is for bash, ... can I use bash from go?

Comment: Yes, you can make a call to OS using `os/exec` package.  It will take some lines of code based around `exec.Command()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is managing to centre the text as long as the shell width is a known value.  Its not quite 'pixel perfect', but I hope it helps.

If we break it down there are two bits of code to produce the format strings to pad right and then left.

```
fmt.Sprintf("%%-%ds", w/2)  // produces "%-55s"  which is pad left string
fmt.Sprintf("%%%ds", w/2)   // produces "%55s"   which is right pad
```

So the final `Printf` statement becomes

```
fmt.Printf("%-55s", fmt.Sprintf("%55s", "my string to centre"))
```

The full code:

```
s := " in the middle"
w := 110 // shell width

fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("%%-%ds", w/2), fmt.Sprintf(fmt.Sprintf("%%%ds", w/2),s))
```

Produces the following:

> ```
>                                      in the middle
> ```

Link to play ground: [play](https://play.golang.org/p/J3mYnzNjEf)

Comment: I've seen. But could you explain a bit "%%-%ds"? Doc says `%% a literal percent sign; consumes no value` what exactly means? `%d is for digit`.

Comment: Updated with better description of the code to produce the format strings.

Comment: I think there's a bug in the solution code, as it does not take into account the width of the string `s`.  See the modified playground code at https://play.golang.org/p/8L5IfEIKSS.  I think you need to replace the first `w/2` with a `w` and the second with a `(w + len(s))/2`, as shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

As an update to this long-answered question, the solution posted by @miltonb can be improved upon by using the `*` notation from the `fmt` package.  From [the package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> In Printf, Sprintf, and Fprintf, the default behavior is for each
> formatting verb to format successive arguments passed in the call.
> However, the notation [n] immediately before the verb indicates that
> the nth one-indexed argument is to be formatted instead. **The same
> notation before a '*' for a width or precision selects the argument
> index holding the value.** After processing a bracketed expression [n],
> subsequent verbs will use arguments n+1, n+2, etc. unless otherwise
> directed.

So you can replace two of the `fmt.Sprintf` calls with a more concise format statement to achieve the same result:

```
s := "in the middle"
w := 110 // or whatever

fmt.Sprintf("%[1]*s", -w, fmt.Sprintf("%[1]*s", (w + len(s))/2, s))
```

[See the code in action](https://play.golang.org/p/pxnJjZe6Bw).

Additionally, as @chris-dennis mentioned, the `[1]` notation is superfluous in this example because the width of the string is already the first argument. This works as well:

```
fmt.Sprintf("%*s", -w, fmt.Sprintf("%*s", (w + len(s))/2, s))
```

[See this example in action](https://play.golang.org/p/NAY601_5JxX).

Comment: Excellent addition regarding the [n] notation, makes it simpler - which is always better.

Comment: Good answer, but in fact it works without the `[1]`s, because in each case the width is the first argument.