# How can I show result of brew leaves in multiple columns?

Tags: bash, terminal, homebrew

`brew leaves` show the result with one column unlike `brew list`, which shows it with multiple columns (actual number depending on the terminal window size). How can I achieve the same effect with `brew leaves`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (much simpler): `brew leaves | column`

---

(Original answer)

Just use: `brew leaves | column -c $(tput cols)`

Explanation:

`|` is a pipe, which connect the output of `brew leaves` to the input of `column -c $(tput cols)`

[column command:](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Linux/shell/commands/column)

> The -c option determines the width of the created table (c stands for console columns, not for table columns).

[find the width & height of a terminal window:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263900/6306190)

> `tput cols` tells you the number of columns.

`$(<your command>)` lets you use the command output as variable.

Comment: You could use the built-in `$COLUMNS` instead of `$(tput cols)`, or even easier, just skip that option as `column` defaults to the full available width.