# Capture output including control characters of subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, tty, control-characters, python-module-unicodedata

I have the following simple program to run a subprocess and `tee` its output to both `stdout` and some buffer

```py
import subprocess
import sys
import time

import unicodedata

p = subprocess.Popen(
    "top",
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

stdout_parts = []
while p.poll() is None:
    for bytes in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        stdout_parts.append(bytes)
        str = bytes.decode("utf-8")
        sys.stdout.write(str)
        for ch in str:
            if unicodedata.category(ch)[0]=="C" and ord(ch) != 10:
                raise Exception(f"control character! {ord(ch)}")
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

When running some terminal updating program, such as `top` or `docker pull`, I want to be able to catch its entire output as well, even if it is not immediately readable as such.

Reading around [How do commands like top update output without appending in the console?](https://superuser.com/questions/1633499/how-do-commands-like-top-update-output-without-appending-in-the-console) for example, it seems it is achieved by control characters.
However, I don't receive any of them when reading lines from the process output streams (stdout/stderr). Or is the technology they use different and I cannot catch it from the subprocess?

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit (the text is still available from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70152093/revisions)); you are more than welcome to post that as an answer, but your question should remain strictly a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many tools adapt their output depending on whether or not they are connected to a terminal. If you want to receive exactly the output you see when running the tool interactively in a terminal, use a wrapper such as `pexpect` to emulate this behavior. (There is also a low-level `pty` library but this is tricky to use, especially if you are new to the problem space.)

Some tools also allow you to specify a batch operation mode for scripting; maybe look into `top -b` (though this is not available e.g. on MacOS).

For the record, many screen control sequences do not consist entirely or even mainly of control characters; for example, the control sequence to move the cursor to a particular position in curses start with an escape character (0x1B), but otherwise consists of regular printable characters. If you really want to process these sequences, probably look into using a curses / ANSI control code parsing library. But for most purposes, a better approach is to use a machine-readable API and disable screen updates entirely.  On Linux, a lot of machine-readable information is available from the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way with which I can set the pseudo terminal size for the subprocess? It seems to know them and print control sequences accordingly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263890/how-do-i-find-the-width-height-of-a-terminal-window is a PHP question but has links to several useful resources. It's a bit of a chicken and egg problem; curses really does try to figure out the size of your screen, but there are some ways you can override that IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Salvaged content from reverted edit to question:

Some solution that prints `top` nicely with the tip from the answer:

```py
import os
import pty
import subprocess
import sys
import time

import select

stdout_master_fd, stdout_slave_fd = pty.openpty()
stderr_master_fd, stderr_slave_fd = pty.openpty()

p = subprocess.Popen(
    "top",
    shell=True,
    stdout=stdout_slave_fd,
    stderr=stderr_slave_fd,
    close_fds=True
)

stdout_parts = []
while p.poll() is None:
    rlist, _, _ = select.select([stdout_master_fd, stderr_master_fd], [], [])
    for f in rlist:
        output = os.read(f, 1000)  # This is used because it doesn't block
        sys.stdout.write(output.decode("utf-8"))
        sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: You really don't want or need `shell=True` here. Switch to `['top']` and drop the `shell=True`.  See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)