# How to wrap git log output based on width of terminal screen?

Tags: git, shell, terminal

I have a custom git log alias, `logge`:

```
git logge -h
'logge' is aliased to 'log --graph --all --color=always --format='%C(yellow)%h %C(blink strike yellow)%>>|(38)%C(reset)%C(auto)%d%>|(35)%C(reset bold blue) %as%C(reset)%x09%C(white)%w(144,0,51)%s %C(bold italic dim white)- %an''
```

This works very well on my default git bash terminal.  But recently I have been using git from within the VS Code terminal, and realised the wrapping in my log alias only works for the specific default size of my usual git bash window.  It does not wrap correctly on a smaller window.

I recall - from when I wrote this alias - noticing an option where I could pass %w() a value of columns from the right of the terminal to wrap at, rather than the default columns from the left.  This would be ideal for my case - I would tell it to wrap at ~2 columns from the right, and it would work in both terminals.  Unfortunately, I cannot remember the required syntax, and I can't find it in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emwltwgtlti1gtlti2gtem).

Does this exist, or did I Hallucinate it?  If it does exist, how do I use it?

Comment: You can get the size of your current terminal using `tput`. bash also keeps `$LINES` and `$COLIMNS` up to date (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263890) )